# The Django form could not be submitted accordingly

Tags: python, django, web

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login/')
def add_country(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CountryForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.edited_by = request.user
            new_form.save()
            return redirect('country_details')
    else:
        form = CountryForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'add_country.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    CONTINENTS = [
        ('Asia','Asia'),
        ('Europe','Europe'),
        ('Africa','Africa'),
        ('Oceania','Oceania'),
        ('North America','North America'),
        ('South America','South America'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=CONTINENTS,null=True)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    food = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    entertainment = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    flag = models.FileField(upload_to='flags', default='default.png',null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='travel', default='default.png',null=True)
    edited_by = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**add_country.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.name.label }}<br>
        {{ form.name }}<br><br>
        {{ form.landmark.label }}<br>
        {{ form.landmark }}<br><br>
        {{ form.food.label }}<br>
        {{ form.food }}<br><br>
        {{ form.entertainment.label }}<br>
        {{ form.entertainment }}<br><br>
        {{ form.flag.label }}<br>
        {{ form.flag }}<br><br>
        {{ form.image.label }}<br>
        {{ form.image }}<br><br>
       
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
    </form>
```

I have an issue that after I added the `edited_by` to assign the currently logged in user into that column then the form could not be submitted and only stayed on the same page instead of redirecting to the page that I want. I have tried different ways to make the form being submitted such as put `request.method == "POST"` and the page didn't work. However before I added `edited_by` into the models the form could be submitted accordingly and the data is being updated. May I ask what is the method to assign the user into the column `edited_by` after that user has added a post?

Comment: can you post your forms too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have included `edited_by` field in your forms too.
If you are handling this field by yourself in the views then remove this field from your forms.

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Country
        exclude = ['edited_by'] # or specify only required fields in form
```

Now your view will work fine.

Note: You can display your form's errors with `{{form.errors}}` in your template.